# Не получается создать таблицу c Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Начал изучение Hibernate.Получаю следующее сообщение:

> мар 25, 2016 6:03:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final} мар 25, 2016 6:03:41 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found мар 25, 2016 6:03:41 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist мар 25, 2016 6:03:41 PM
>   org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver
>   resolveEntity WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate
>   namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration.
>   Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration
>   instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at
>   any time. мар 25, 2016 6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} мар 25, 2016 6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) мар 25, 2016 6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>   at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test] мар 25, 2016 6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root,
>   password=****} мар 25, 2016 6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false мар 25, 2016
>   6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1) Fri
>   Mar 25 18:03:42 MSK 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
>   server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL
>   5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
>   with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
>   property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
>   by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
>   server certificate verification. мар 25, 2016 6:03:42 PM
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect мар 25, 2016 6:03:43 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl
>   applyImportSources INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script
>   'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@4d0f2471'

Файл hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <!-- a SessionFactory instance listed as /jndi/name -->
    <session-factory
        name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory">
          <!-- properties -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="user.cfg.xml"/>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Файл  user.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="User" table="user">
 <id name="id" column="id"><generator class="native"/></id>
 <property name="firstname" column="first_name" type="string"/>
  <property name="lasttname" column="last_name" type="string"/>
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Непонятно, в чем проблема? Хибер не подключается к базе или что? Все что я вижу в логах - это предупреждения, но не ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в классе где прописан `SessionFactory` следующий код:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    static {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```